# if Excel Workbook is open then...... VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How could I write code to say.

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
```

if an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) Workbook is already open then....

```
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    elseif xlApp is nothing then
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\InspectionCreator\InspectionSheet.xlsx")
End if
```

I don't want it to have to be a specific workbook just any workbook I can't seem to find anything on the internet. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Where is this code going to be running from ?

Comment: Are you thinking of say, VBScript?

Comment: the codes going to be running solidworks which it is pretty much independent like vb6

Answer (score 7):

First try using getobject: if it throws an error then use createobject:

```
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

  On Error Resume Next
  Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  On Error GoTo 0

  If xlApp Is Nothing Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
  End If
```

Comment: if xlapp is nothing does work the first part I am having problems with

Answer (score 3):

I used to run code very similar to Tim's until Kevin Jones pointed out in an Experts-Exchange post that I will repeat here (as the EE post is behind the paywall)

*"Be aware that when launching Excel through automation using the CreateObject function, Excel does not load any Add-Ins or other workbooks normally loaded automatically. This is not a good way to start an Excel session that will be used by the user. To start an Excel application instance without using automation from any application other than Excel, the Excel application must be launched using non-automation means. The code below illustrates the steps to do this. The code first tries to obtain an automation handle to an existing application instance. If an existing instance is not found then a new instance is started using the Shell command."*

```
 Dim ExcelApplication As Object
   Dim TimeoutTime As Long

   On Error Resume Next
   Set ExcelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0
   If ExcelApplication Is Nothing Then
       Shell "Excel.exe"
       TimeoutTime = Timer + 5
       On Error Resume Next
       Do
           DoEvents
           Err.Reset
           Set ExcelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
       Loop Until Not ExcelApplication Is Nothing Or Timer > TimeoutTime
       On Error GoTo 0
   End If
   If ExcelApplication Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "Unable to launch Excel."
   Else
       ' Do something with the Excel instance...
   End If
```

Comment: I like this concept.  It will make your app more robust.  It's better to tell the user that it can't launch Excel instead of the typical "can't create object".

Answer (score 1):

This might be going in the wrong direction but here's something I've used in the past..

```
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then 'Or in your case = 0
       'Do Something Here'
    Else
       'Do Something Else'
    End If
```

That way it will tell you if you have more than one workbook open. Otherwise it sounds like you ARE looking to see if something specific is open.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Dam can't believe that works that is an awesome solution Thanks

Comment: Anytime, And yep. I like the elegant simple solutions the best.

Comment: Given you are automating Excel I don't see how the code above works - `Workbooks.Count` is for running VBA inside the active Application.

Comment: Not if the program he is using uses a combination of Office classes. Then it might be programmed to say "Give me a count of how many Workbook classes are open at this moment". Apparently it did work though. But you're right, I always used it inside other excel sheets. Usually to hide windows to make forms seem like their own program.

Comment: There are always smug programmers on here I hate that