# Activate/select a word-document and find the value of active cell in that document

Tags: excel, vba, search, ms-word, find

I want to select a cell and use the value-text in that cell, to search/find in a specific word-document (xxxxxx.docx). This document is already opened, together with other word-documents.

The code underneath does what I want… almost. It OPENS the specific document, and then finds the text. But the document is already open, so it doesnt work good for the job. It just needs to be selected/activated and not opening again.

Does someone knows how to manage this: Select any cell, use the value in that cell, activate/select xxxxxx.docx, and search that value.

** It is most important the found text is shown in the document, that has to show/pop-up in the screen. All this is meant to navigate fast in this document.

```
Sub FindName()

    Dim wrdApp As Object
    Dim wrdDoc As Object
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\xxxxxx.docx")
    Dim FindWord As String
    Dim result As String
    FindWord = ActiveCell.Value
    wrdDoc.SelectAllEditableRanges

    With wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
        .Text = FindWord
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try 'wrdApp.Documents.Content' and look for the value in the content?

Comment: Your Word related variables should be public and you should make different subs to check first if the documents are already open or not. If the documen is not opened, then open it and execute your code. If it's already open, just activate that document and execute your code.

Comment: I answered a very similar question not so long ago: [Edit a workbook, whether open or closed, from Word VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119174/edit-a-workbook-whether-open-or-closed-from-word-vba). It was written for a question going "the other way", but the same principles apply when automating Word from Excel. Read through that answer to see the various ways to interact with another Office application when it may or may not be running and a file may or may not be open.

Answer (score 1):

If the document is already open, then Word must already be running. In which case you don't want either:

- Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application"); or
- Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\xxxxxx.docx")

You should start by checking whether Word is running and, if so, whether the document is open. Hence:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Const StrNm As String = "C:\xxxxxx.docx"
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err Then
  Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With wdApp
  For Each wdDoc In .Documents
    If wdDoc.FullName = "StrNm" Then Exit For
  Next
  If wdDoc Is Nothing Then Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(StrNm)
    'to Find & navigate to a particular string
    With wdDoc.Range
      With .Find
        .Text = ActiveCell.Value
        .Execute
      End If
      If .Find.Found = True Then .Select
    End With
    'To navigate to a particular bookmark
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range.Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Macropod,
I think this is what I want!! As a test I made a msgbox if text is found, and it works. However I need the word document to show, at the point where is the text. Is this possible? It need to navigate to and in the word-document. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why do you *need* to navigate to that point? Almost all editing of a document via code can be done without that. In any event, show us what you have tried.

Comment: That is the whole thing, the navigation to the found text. All this is meant to navigate fast, because the document has 1000+ pages, and many bookmarks. I am breaking my head only to navigate. The code I wrote before did the navigation, but was unusable because it opens it al the time. Your code is almost there, could you give it the last push?

Comment: If you're using bookmarks, you don't even need Find!!! See revised code.

Comment: You are the best of the best. I cannot thank you enough! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Macropod and other helpers,
The newest code was a success! I changed it a little, taking out the bookmark search, and I was lucky! To make the word-document show in the screen I used the shell… I know this must hurt your eyes, or break the screen, but it does work (without it Word stays minimized). If someone wants to make this prettier, I would love to learn from it. But it works and I am happy. Thank you very much, I enjoy it! Super helpful.

```
    Sub Demo()
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Const StrNm As String = "C:\xxxxxx.docx"
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err Then
  Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With wdApp
  For Each wdDoc In .Documents
    If wdDoc.FullName = "StrNm" Then Exit For
  Next
  If wdDoc Is Nothing Then Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(StrNm)
    With wdDoc.Range
      With .Find
        .Text = ActiveCell.Value
        .Execute
      End With
      If .Find.Found = True Then .Select
    End With
    End With
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & "C:\xxxxxx.docx" & "", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```