# PowerPoint VBA: get data from already open Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

By clicking a button in PowerPoint I'd like to get some cell values from the currently open Excel workbook (whichever workbook is open at the time of clicking the button).

In PowerPoint VBA, the Microsoft Excel 16.0 object library is enabled.

But running:

```
sss = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
MsgBox sss
```

gives this error:

```
Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
```

How can I request a cell value from the active workbook?

Comment: You need to provide more code context. We need to see how you're addressing Excel. PowerPoint won't know anything about `ActiveWorkbook` without a reference to the Excel application. If this is all you have, research the method `GetObject` for how to pick up a running instance of an application. This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119174/edit-a-workbook-whether-open-or-closed-from-word-vba/60125238#60125238

Comment: @CindyMeister There was no mode code context. I was under the impression that the object library would allow me to use ActiveWorkbook directly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to qualify your workbook reference.  First, use `GetObject` to get the existing instance of Excel, as @Cindy Meister has suggested.

```
Dim excelApplication As Excel.Application
Set excelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

For late binding, though, you can dispense with a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object library and declare the application variable as `Object`.

```
Dim excelApplication As Object
Set excelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

Then, qualify your workbook reference as follows...

```
Dim ss As String
ss = excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

So you would have the following...

```
Dim excelApplication As Object
Set excelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Dim ss As String
ss = excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

MsgBox ss, vbInformation

Set excelApplication = Nothing
```