# Editing Excel from Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I found "Edit a workbook, whether open or closed, from Word VBA" ([Edit a workbook, whether open or closed, from Word VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119174/edit-a-workbook-whether-open-or-closed-from-word-vba/60125238#60125238)) and it works great on my personal PC, but when I use the same code on my company's PC, "File in Use" "Test.xlxs is locked for editing" and Run-time error -2147467259 (80004095) occurs. I'm guessing this because the macro started a new/different session or instance, and cannot open a workbook that's currently running.

Is there a way to alter Cindy Meister's code to detect a specific open excel workbook in a different session/instance? Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: If the Excel file is opened by user, `Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` will get the Excel object.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The original code follows your logic and works on my PC, but not on the company PC. Using break, “If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then…” doesn’t detect Excel and starts a separate instance, attempting to open the file that’s already running.  I ran a separate subroutine using “Check whether a specific workbook is open” and it returned False.  Is there a way to determine the number of Excel instances running? Again, thank you for your interest in solving this problem.

Comment: The solution is to set Word and Excel to "Run as Administrator".